# ionic3 error on android when calling GET HTTP

Tags: android, http, ionic-framework, cors, ionic3

In Ionic3 I installed `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';` and in my code I'm trying to call below url :

```
testHTTP(){
this.httpClient.get("https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup?upc=5425016921463").subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log('Data : ', data);
    this.lookup = data["items"][0].title;
  }, err => {
    console.log('Error : ', err);
    this.lookup = JSON.stringify(err);
});
}
```

but every time it fails with :

> {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}

When I click on the button calling testHTTP on `Chrome`, I get a CORS error with this object (but I can deactivate CORS and get the real response).

How do you setup ionic http for the get to work please ?

Comment: Can you share the result after deactivating CORS?

Comment: on chrome it's the json returned by the API i'm trying to call : {"code":"OK","total":1,"offset":0,"items":[{"ean":"5425016921463","title":"Concept (français) Concept Neuf","description": ...

so `this.lookup` is now "Concept (français) Concept Neuf" and it is written on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You should use a XMLHttpRequest. And dont forget the Headers.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup?upc=5425016921463", true);

//Really important to set this header
xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","http://localhost:8100"); 

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {
  let ResponseFromRequest = xhr.response //Response from your request   
}

}

xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: On `chrome` : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.upcitemdb.com/prod/trial/lookup?upc=5425016921463' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.upcitemdb.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
On `Android` : response is empty (alert(ResponseFromRequest) opens empty alert)

Comment: Yes, the reason for this may be because your server (localhost) dont has https and isnt secure

Comment: ok, anyway the problem was with android, so it doesnt solve it. I tried using http from cordova http extended and it works (but it doesnt on windows since it's only for ios/android). Is XMLHttpRequest supposed to work on android too ? what's the difference with http extended ? Thank you !